# How to connect a remote nodejs bin to a local Vagrant VM from WebStorm

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have installed `Nodejs` in a Vagrant virtual machine. We call it `nodejs remote`. I would run `remote nodejs` from `webstorm` application. I have installed vagrant plugin from that application. In the settings I might set the path of the node interpreter but since it is into the virtual machine how can I reach it?

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7379?pr=webStorm